# Error: Creating default object from empty value laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

First of all, I want to say that I've already search this problem before ask this question.
My problem is, I am writing restful controller in Laravel 5.1. 
Below is my code:

1- Here is HocSinhController.php,

```
 public function create()
{
   return view('restful.add');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $hocinh = new HocSinh();
    $hocsinh->hoten = $request->txtHoTen;
    $hocsinh->toan = $request->txtToan;
    $hocsinh->ly = $request->txtLy;
    $hocsinh->hoa = $request->txtHoa;
    $hocsinh->save();
}
```

2- Here form of add.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{!! route('hocsinh.store') !!}" name="frmAdd">
        <input type= "hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lblHoTen">Họ Tên Học Sinh</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtHoTen" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lblToan">Điểm Môn Toán</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtToan" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lblLy">Điểm Môn Lý</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtLy" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lblHoa">Điểm Môn Hóa</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtHoa" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Thêm</button>
      </form>
```

3- Here route that I declaire in my route.php

```
Route::resource('hocsinh', 'HocSinhController');
```

Actually In "HocSinhController.php" I already import the model "HocSinh" like this: "use App\HocSinh;" But it's still appear the error. When I type the url: "http://localhost/hocsinh/create", the "add.blade.php" form will be show, after I enter all information and click "Thêm" button, It's will appear error: "creating default object from empty value".

Please help me to check it out.

Thanks you so much

Comment: Change `$hocinh = new HocSinh();` to `$hocsinh = new HocSinh();`

Comment: Oh my god, thanks youuuu, it's my fault :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how you `get` the values from your form using the `$request` variable:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $hocinh = new HocSinh();
    $hocsinh->hoten = $request->get('txtHoTen');
    $hocsinh->toan = $request->get('txtToan');
    $hocsinh->ly = $request->get('txtLy');
    $hocsinh->hoa = $request->get('txtHoa');
    $hocsinh->save();
}
```

You need to use `$request`'s `get()` method.

Comment: I've fixed already, thanks you. But my mistake is at $hocsinh variable. After correct this variable it's worked. I think both $request->txtHoTen and  $request->get('txtHoTen') is OK.